# Fragment onDestroy() vs Service onDestroy()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

I need to execute some code when the user swipes up on their recents list (kills the app).

When the app is killed, both my Fragment/Activity and Foreground Service are destroyed.

However, which `onDestroy()` method should I use to execute the code?

Here is my current setup:

**Fragment.kt**

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    countDownTimer.cancel()
    user1Listener?.remove()
    stopService()
    super.onDestroy()
    mapView?.onDestroy()
}

private fun stopMeetupService(){
    val intent = Intent(mContext.applicationContext, MyService::class.java)
    activity?.stopService(intent)
}
```

**MyService.kt**

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.user_data), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val docId = sharedPref.getString("docId", null)
    val docData = mapOf<String, Any?>(
        "user2" to "",
        "location" to null
    )
    if (docId != null && docId.isNotBlank()) {
        db.collection("docs").document(docId).update(docData).addOnSuccessListener {
        }
    }
}
```

Realistically, both sets of code could be merged into the one `onDestroy()` - ideally whichever method is more reliable to fire.

Comment: I don't think either will work as swiping away from recents should kill your apps JVM process instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, if you want to stop service only when kill app from recent.  Because in some case your service may also stop if you replace the fragments.

So stoping service should `Application` level and not a Activity/Fragment level in your case

Here is code

**AppLifecycleHandler**

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.Application
import android.content.ComponentCallbacks2
import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.os.Bundle

class AppLifecycleHandler(private val lifeCycleDelegate: LifeCycleDelegate) : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, ComponentCallbacks2 {

override fun onActivityPaused(p0: Activity?) {
}

override fun onActivityResumed(p0: Activity?) {
}

override fun onActivityStarted(p0: Activity?) {
}

override fun onActivityDestroyed(p0: Activity?) {
         lifeCycleDelegate.onAppDestroyed(p0)
}

override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(p0: Activity?, p1: Bundle?) {
}

override fun onActivityStopped(p0: Activity?) {
}

override fun onActivityCreated(p0: Activity?, p1: Bundle?) {
}

override fun onLowMemory() {}

override fun onConfigurationChanged(p0: Configuration?) {}

override fun onTrimMemory(level: Int) {

}

}

interface LifeCycleDelegate {
   fun onAppDestroyed(p0: Activity?)
}
```

**Application** class : override `onAppDestroyed` in Application class and stop service here

```
class App : LifeCycleDelegate {
....
....

override fun onAppDestroyed(p0: Activity?) {
    val intent = Intent(p0, MyService::class.java)
    p0?.stopService(intent)
 }
}
```